# What does this "button" in gmail do?

Tags: gmail

*[image: emphasized text]*

I cannot get the use of this button in the gmail sign in page , does it specify anything ?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt see the usage of this also.

```
<div class="goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown"></div>
```

There is no action related this code. Maybe someone forgot it.

Comment: someone forgot ? . Does it mean it passed through all the testing un-noticed? @Cracker

Comment: Maybe it was using for language option, by generation new css maybe it became useless who knows :)